# Different sizes on 2 devices, even if I use "dp"

Tags: android, text, size, screen, dimension

I've 2 tablets:

1 Samsung Android 3.0

```
    DisplayMetrics {density=1.0, width=600, height=976, 
scaledDensity=1.0, xdpi=161.55031, ydpi=155.51021}
```

1 Low cost device, Android 2.3.3

```
    DisplayMetrics {density=1.0, width=480, height=800, 
scaledDensity=1.0, xdpi=160, ydpi=160.42105}
```

If I use different layout for each screen size, both devices says they are large-long and mdpi, so I can't distinguish them by using layout folder names... The problem is:

I use a TextView with textSize="20dp"

In the firse device, text width is half of the screen, in the second device is bigger (80% of the screen width). Why? I expect that both devices display text in the same way if I use dp (and not px). I tried also with sp but nothing changes...

(I used TextView as example, I've the same problem with all elements in the layout: button sizes, ...)

I would try to use layout folder names like "layout-w600dp" or something else introduced in Android 3.2 but this is not the case.

I know I can change element dimensions by code in onLayout() but I don't want to do that...

Any suggestion?

**Update**

I solved my problems with layouts using themes: [Activate a specific dimens.xml at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11312398/android-activate-a-specific-dimens-xml-at-runtime/11342177#11342177)

Comment: I am having the exact problem with 2 similar hardwares.  Did styles solve the problem for text size and images ?how do you know which layout to pick if both devices cant be destinguished

Comment: How can you say that the 2 devices are not distinguishable? Have you tried looking at density and resolution? Are DisplayMetrics both the same?

Comment: I have both devices showing display metrics as you showed it. Both similar with a small difference in xdpi,ydpi. When I said they are the same I meant they are both medium desnity large screen size devices. Yet the image sizes/button size is different

Comment: That little difference is enough to distinguish each device type. I tried to solve this problem in different ways and the most reliable is to write some "if()" and activate a specific theme at run time. I'm running on Android 2.2 as base so I can't use layout tricks introduced in Android 3.2 as described here http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html (If you find my question usefull please vote for it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [android documentation on Dimention](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Dimension) say this

> The ratio of dp-to-pixel will change with the screen density, but not necessarily in direct proportion

So it's totally ok what you see

You can achieve 50% of the screen using LinearLayout weigth..Refer [this](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/02/android-layout-tricks-1.html)

Comment: In my case density seems to be the same for both device. My need is to display a text exactly in the same way on both device, adjusting a layout weight is a solution but not so usefull for this case: if I use a layout with 50% of screen width, in the first device text is displayed in one line, in the second device text is displayed in 2 lines...