# Activate a specific dimens.xml at runtime

Tags: android, layout, runtime, dimension

I need to choose a specific dimens.xml at runtime after my app checks for screen capabilities. I DON'T WANT ANDROID CHOOSE IT FOR ME by selecting automatically by project folder (\values, \values-large, ...).

I have to do it manually due to the bad screen configuration (density and dimension) of my low-cost china tablet. Can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved using styles/themes/... and activating a specific theme at runtime in onCreate() as described here:

[android dynamically change style at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3241729/android-dynamically-change-style-at-runtime)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to force configuration change?

```
    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    metrics.densityDpi = DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM;
    metrics.setTo(metrics);
```

Not sure if it works though. It's generally a bad idea to ignore what the OS thinks is the best.